# Docker micro-containers

Tags: docker, containers, alpine-linux

I'm experimenting with Micro-containers. I created the following Dockerfile. The idea is that this Docker file starts with a very small base image. (5 MB) Installs the build tools, does the build and then removes the build tool.

```
FROM alpine
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/dockerdemo"]

RUN apk update
RUN apk add -t build-deps build-base go git

COPY . /go/src/dockerdemo

RUN cd /go/src/dockerdemo \
    && export GOPATH=/go \
    && go get \
    && go build -o /bin/dockerdemo \
    && rm -rf /go

RUN apk del --purge build-base go git
```

I was expecting it to be really small. But it is 358 MB. It appears that the last command did not actually delete the build components.

I'm pretty new to Docker so I may be completely missing something here.

It's also possible that the file system on the image doesn't get compacted, so even though the build component files are gone the file system is still 358 MB.

Answer (score 1):

Each `COMMAND` in a docker file can commit a new [image file system layer](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/), if the step makes change to the file system.

Even if you `RUN rm -rf /` after all other steps, the image would still have the contents of each previous layer stored in the image.

Do the installs and removes in the one `RUN` step to avoid committing the file system changes you don't want to keep:

```
FROM alpine
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/dockerdemo"]

COPY . /go/src/dockerdemo

RUN set -uex; \
    apk update; \
    apk add -t build-deps build-base go git; \
    cd /go/src/dockerdemo; \
    export GOPATH=/go; \
    go get; \
    go build -o /bin/dockerdemo; \
    rm -rf /go; \
    apk del --purge build-base go git
```

You will notice when using this setup, all steps will have to be run every time so you lose some of Dockers caching niceness.

#### Build Image

If you have issues with the build turnaround times, an alternative is to have a specific build image that is seperate from the image you run the application with.

One of the cool things about Go is you can [build static binaries](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/07/osx-static-golang-binaries-with-docker/) with no dependencies and run them `FROM scratch` resulting in a truely micro container.

As Mark O'Connor noted, you probably don't need to setup your own image for the build as you can use the official [golang image](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/).

```
FROM golang

COPY . /go/src/dockerdemo

RUN set -uex; \
    cd /go/src/dockerdemo; \
    export GOPATH=/go; \
    go get; \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -ldflags "-s" -a -installsuffix cgo -o /bin/dockerdemo;
```

Extract the binary from the image

```
docker run go-build tar -cvf /bin/dockerdemo > dockerdemo.tar
```

Build the app container from it

```
FROM scratch
ADD dockerdemo.tar /
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/dockerdemo"]
```

Comment: Yes it takes awhile to build so going to a build and a run image makes sense. Doesn't the command "ADD dockerdemo.tar /" leave a tar file on the file system? Or does ADD support tar files implicitly and do the extraction automtically?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/add  If <src> is a local tar archive in a recognized compression format (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory. Resources from remote URLs are not decompressed. When a directory is copied or unpacked, it has the same behavior as tar -x

Comment: [Multistage docker builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build) are the way to go these days.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not `build-deps`, `build-base`, `go`, and/or `git` that take up the 350 MB?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the official golang image from Docker hub? It has an alpine option.

https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/

Checkout **1.8-alpine** Dockerfile:

- https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/b819b526131d44c03f02942816f616067d389037/1.8/alpine/Dockerfile

---

Docker is a layered append file system. This means files are not truly deleted. You'll need to to an export/import to compact everything down to a single layer.